# What are the weapon ranges?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

More specifically, how many tiles away do I have to be before I get bonus accuracy on my shotgun? Closest things I've found are [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/1ri366/weapon_ranges_and_hit_chance_what_are_the_numbers/) and [At what range do various weapons get range bonuses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255340/at-what-range-do-various-weapons-get-range-bonuses). The latter is for XCOM 2. The reddit thread says,

> Shotguns have about 50 aim bonus at 1 range, 0 bonus at 10 tiles, 29 penalty at 15 tiles.

But the UFOpaedia link is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9 tiles, put simply.

9 tiles straight is the range at which most weapons' aim changes. 6 diagonal, if I'm reading [this Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hlQDpGadtt54pBbHmJyxIigyWNDvCKwAdwPXUIKAHIk/edit#gid=0) correctly.

- Shotguns get a proportional bonus if less than that distance. Proportional penalty if greater than that distance. Ranging from +52% to -40%.
- Sniper rifles get a proportional penalty if less than that distance (up to -24%).
- Rifles, LMGS, and pistols get a proportional bonus if less than that distance (up to +37%).

https://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php/Chance_to_Hit_(EU2012)#Weapon_Range

The Arc Thrower has a maximum range of 3 tiles. Its odds of success are 49/70/80/90% at 4/3/2/1 enemy HP respectively.